# C# add event handler literal code block

Tags: c#, event-handling

Is it possible to add a literal code block as an event handler in C#? Something like:

```
Timer t = new Timer(1000);
t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler({ Console.WriteLine("Tick"); });
```

You can do this in PowerShell, so I thought there might be some way to do this in C# too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a lambda expression (C# 3.0 and higher):

```
t.Elapsed += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("Tick");
```

or an anonymous method (C# 2.0 and higher):

```
// If you don't need the parameter values
t.Elapsed += delegate { Console.WriteLine("Tick"); };

// If you do need the parameter values
t.Elapsed += delegate(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Tick from {0}", sender); 
};
```

Comment: Interesting, did not know that you can omit parameter declaration with the `delegate` syntax.

Comment: stackoverflow etiquette: Shoud I ask "how do I remove an anonymous event handler" here or in a separate question?

Comment: @jmh_gr: Search for it, as it's almost certainly been asked before :) (But otherwise, ask a new question... and the answer is that you assign it to a variable, then subscribe and unsubscribe with the same variable.)

Comment: ... in which case an ordinary event handler method would be easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

```
t.Elapsed += delegate(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
             { 
                 Console.WriteLine["Tick"]; 
             });
```

Or, you could also use lambda syntax:

```
t.Elapsed += (sender, args) => { Console.WriteLine["Tick"]; };
```

Comment: That won't work as-written - you need to remove `()` otherwise it's *requiring* a delegate type with no parameters.

Comment: @Jon - Yeah. Realized that after I posted both versions. Fixed them both.