# Why can anonymous delegates omit arguments, but lambdas can't?

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, arguments

```
//ok
Action<int> CallbackWithParam1 = delegate { };    

//error CS1593: Delegate 'System.Action<int>' does not take 0 arguments
Action<int> CallbackWithParam2 = () => { };
```

Just wondered why the discrepancy really. :-/

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not really a good reason for it, like @JaredPar says below. Just something that was omitted (whether intentionally or not, I'm not sure).

Comment: This looks like a job for... Eric Lippert man!

Comment: @Tudor Insert Batman theme here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Jared is of course correct. To add a couple more details:

- Almost no one uses the "skip the parameter list" syntax.
- We have no scenario for lambdas that *requires* that feature.
- The feature complicates type inference and overload resolution, and makes it more likely that both will fail.
- What syntax would you like for the feature?  `Action<int> c = => {};` ??? I have no desire whatsoever to make `=>` into a unary prefix operator.

So on the one hand we have the list of pros:

- Lambdas gain consistency with an unnecessary C# 2.0 feature that hardly anyone knows about or uses -- a feature that frankly, we wish we'd never done in the first place

and the cons:

- implementation complicates already-complex type inference and overload resolution algorithms
- feature leads to more bug possibilities for users with no corresponding gain in representational power.
- no obviously nice syntax

If you were given that list of pros and cons, what would you do?  I hope "implement the feature" would not be your choice; it was not ours.

Comment: "Almost no one uses the 'skip the parameter list' syntax." Heck, I didn't even know it existed.

Comment: "hardly anyone knows about or uses" ... And yet I've seen that syntax for _event_ delegates, as in `button1.Click += delegate { MessageBox.Show("Hello world"); };`. It was even suggested by two different people in response to a question of my own (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530743/c-sharp-add-event-handler-literal-code-block). Would you really consider that a different case?

Comment: Cool! It appears I can summon Eric Lippert!

Comment: @jmh_gr: It's also my preferred way of preventing a `NullReferenceException` when raising a field-like event, by initializing the backing field to `delegate { }`.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanation. I didn't have any massive desire for parameterless lambdas, just idly wondering why the discrepancy, which you have answered fully. Thanks.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer: Good question anyway. I'm also often puzzled why some things got implemented in .NET and others didn't. At least here on SO there is a good choice to get a good answer.

Answer (score 6):

It's essentially as simple as they are different features with different sets of supported scenarios.  It's almost like asking

> Why can lambdas be expressions but delegates can only be blocks?